# Limiting Playa results in loop for use in slider

Tags: playa

I want to output my Playa relationship entries into a slideshow. The relationships are linked to a channel field that has one image per listing. The tricky thing is that I want to output 5 images per row for use in the slideshow. Any advice on how I could do this? I've posted my code below, in which all the entries are returned (All images are being spit out in one slide).

```
    <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
        data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
        data-cycle-timeout="1000"
        data-cycle-slides="> div"
        >
        {exp:channel:entries channel="home" dynamic="off" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
            <div>
                <ul class="client-list">
                    {exp:playa:children}
                    <li><div style="background: url({exp:ed_imageresizer image="{logos}" alt="{title}" maxWidth="160" maxHeight="80" href_only="yes"}) no-repeat center center; hfive: 98px;" cropratio="116:104"></div></li>
                    {/exp:playa:children}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to conditionally output your html. You can do this with the [`switch`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#switch) variable (which is supported within Playa loops), or using an add-on you can use [modulo](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=modulo&collection=addons&addon_version_support=).

If I understand your jQuery Cycle setup and and how you want the HTML output to be structured, then the following should do the trick:

Use `switch` to close the list of images and the `div` that represents a slide every 5 child entries. At the same time, open a new slide `div` and image list to contain the next round of children.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="home" dynamic="off" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
    <div>
        <ul class="client-list">
            {exp:playa:children}

                <li><div style="background: url({exp:ed_imageresizer image="{logos}" alt="{title}" maxWidth="160" maxHeight="80" href_only="yes"}) no-repeat center center; hfive: 98px;" cropratio="116:104"></div></li>

                {switch='||||</ul></div><div><ul class="client-list">'}

            {/exp:playa:children}
        </ul>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: This is exactly correct and works perfectly! Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you only want five list items per ul.client-list, `{exp:playa:children limit="5"}` should work, I think.

Otherwise, you'll need to look at the `switch` option outlined by Alex.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it's Alex's solution I was looking for. Appreciate your input.